# How to configure SQLite3 for PHP 5.6.14 on Apache 2.4 (Windows 7)?

Tags: php, sqlite, apache2.4, php-5.6

I'm on Windows 7, using PHP Version 5.6.14 on Apache 2.4 and I'm trying to access to a SQLite3 database.

I'm obtaining ....

***Fatal error***: Class 'SQLite3' not found

Here you're a simple php code ...

```
<?php
  $db = new SQLite3('phpdb');

  if ($db) {
    $db->query("CREATE TABLE dogbreeds (Name VARCHAR(255), MaxAge INT);");
    $db->query("INSERT INTO dogbreeds VALUES ('Doberman', 15)");
    $result = $db->query("SELECT Name FROM dogbreeds");
    var_dump($result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC));
  } else {
    print "Connection to database failed!\n";
  }
?>
```

I've just looking for information about and based on this at the moment I've this configuration in my php.ini file ...

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
sqlite3.extension_dir = "D:\Cesare\Lavoro\Utili\Php\5-6-14\ext"
```

Any suggestions? Thank you very much in advance ....

Cesare

Comment: Do the output of `<?php phpinfo();` in a blank webpage states that SQLite3 is enabled and working properly ?

Comment: I can see that PDO support - PDO drivers (PDO)  and PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x - SQLite Library (pdo_sqlite) are enabled but nothing more ..... Thanks!

Comment: PDO_SQLite3 is actually a different extension, (it is the PDO Driver), you could either refactor your code to use PDO instead, or check the presence of `php_sqlite3.dll` in the php extensions directory. You might also want to double-check that the php.ini you looked up is the right one (`phpinfo();` can help there too)

Comment: I've enabled PDO_SQLite3 too as last attempt  ... :-). I've just checked the presence of php_sqlite3.dll in the php extensions directory, and the php.in is the right one. Do you think that my configuration enabled are the all ones I need to enable or there are others?

Comment: Well if everything was ok you should see an SQLite3 section in the phpinfo() page and you wouldn't get the error message you reported. In case you recently edited the php configuration files you might restart the webserver and check again the phpinfo() page.

Comment: @Calimero starting from your suggestion about to check the right one php.ini, I've checked the rows about extensions enabling .... I've tried to cancel them and rewrite them and now all it's working fine .... Mystery! the problem now is SOLVED and my php.ini configurations was right. Thanks to your suggestions that made me try to change something

Comment: glad to have been of help :)

Answer (score 6):

Enable extension php by removing the ";" in front of ";extension=php_sqlite3.dll" in php.ini. Can you also manually check if the extensions are there in the path?

```
`extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll` AND `extension=php_sqlite3.dll`.
```

Try this

```
$db = sqlite_open("/absolute/path/my_sqlite.db");
```

or

```
 $db = new SQLiteDatabase('filename'))
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem, I solved it by changing the "extension_dir" using the absolute path

```
extension_dir = "C:/php/php7.0/ext"
```

the others setting

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
sqlite3.extension_dir = "C:/php/php7.0/ext"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem:
-I am doing the LinkedIn Learning for SQL Essentials.

-My OS is windows server 2012 r2

-I downloaded xampp from this website https://bw.org/ldcsql/, given by the instructor. I specifically downloaded the xampp version on this website even though there is a newer one(I uninstalled the newer one and installed the one from the website).

-Installed sqlite from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html (downloaded sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3240000.zip for my computer and the "sqlite-tools-win32-86-3240000.zip"). I unzipped them and copied the DLL and the def(from dll 64) to system32 folder and the "sqlite3" Application (from sqlite-tools) to system32 as well.
A reference website just in case https://mislav.net/rails/install-sqlite3/

Note: when I say "install" it means that I pasted the files to the system32, there is no wizard installation or anything else.

-In C:\xampp\php I looked for the php.ini which is of type "Configuration Settings", is NOT the php.ini-production NOR the php.ini-development. Inside there these should be uncommented:  extension=pdo_mysql, extension=pdo_sqlite and extension=sqlite3.

-Also in C:\xampp\php\ext check that you have php_pdo_mysql.dll, php_pdo_sqlite.dll and php_pdo_sqlite3.dll

And after all that it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAMPP click on "config" button select PHP(php.ini) then search "sqlite3" uncomment the ;extension=sqlite3 like this, extension=sqlite3 then find [sqlite3] and write the path where your php file and sqlite database reside like, [sqlite3]
sqlite3.extension_dir ="D:\xampp\htdocs" then type localhost/yourphpfile.php in your browser you'll see the results of query.

Answer (score -1):

System
xuname: Void 4.19.118_1 armv7l Unknown uptodate rF
package: php-7.4.5_1, php-sqlite-7.4.5_1
Actual behavior
I'm trying to get the PHP SQLite3 extension to work on my Raspberry PI. I installed the above packages and enabled the extension in /etc/php/php.ini by uncommenting ;extension=sqlite3.

Executing php -m does not list sqlite as a PHP module.
Executing php -i does not mention any SQLite3 support.

Expected behavior
SQLite3 should work after installing php-sqlite-7.4.5_1 and enabling the extension in /etc/php/php.ini.

Steps to reproduce the behavior
Install the above packages, enable SQLite3 extension and run php -r 'new SQLite3("db");':